# error in migrating cvs to git

Tags: git, cvs

I have migrated a cvs repository to git repository.

But in the middle it gets quit and it says the error as Unknown: Error

What is the reason? How can I overcome from this? Any help much appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

**Sample output:**

```
New vfiles/alarms/4003_182.wav: 80044 bytes
Fetching vfiles/alarms/4003_183.wav   v 1.1
New vfiles/alarms/4003_183.wav: 92044 bytes
Fetching vfiles/alarms/4003_184.wav   v 1.1
New vfiles/alarms/4003_184.wav: 80044 bytes
Fetching vfiles/alarms/4003_19.wav   v 1.1
New vfiles/alarms/4003_19.wav: 72044 bytes
Fetching vfiles/alarms/4003_2.wav   v 1.1
Unknown: error
```

Comment: add the -v flag to make the program more verbose

Comment: @robinr : I have already used the -v option. The command will be like this git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:thillaiselvan@<path_to_cvs_server> -r cvs -k <module_name>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just run into the same issue. The "Unknown: error" is not from "git cvsimport" (which I suspect is what you're trying to do), but from "cvsps" (which is called by cvsimport under the hood). You can use the -p option to "git cvsimport" to pass additional options to "cvsps".

For me, the problem was a broken "~/.cvsps/cvsps.cache" file. Starting my git commandline like

```
git cvsimport -p "-x" [...]
```

(causing cvsps to rebuild its cache) fixed it for me.